# My redirect URL doesn't show any pages on my website

Tags: redirect, urls, hosting, ftp, iframe

I recently started using Wordpress. To do so I installed wordpress on my FTP server. Everything is working perfectly fine so far, except for my page URL.

My FTP server's URL is really complicated so I bought an domain name and redirected it to the FTP server. The site is called **jongbeleggen.com** . However, because I redirected with something called 'transparancy' (some kind of iframe), my site is only showing jongbeleggen.com no matter what page I go to.

Example:
When I go to my website, the URL jongbeleggen.com is showing. Then when I click on my Blog page it should say jongbeleggen.com/blog . However, it says jongbeleggen.com

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with this issue or tell me what iam doing wrong!

Thank you in Advance!

Peter

Comment: Well the iframe is the issue (and I don't think "transparency redirection" is a standard industry practice) - iframes displaying another address don't share their URL with the webpage they're displayed on. You could use JavaScript to update the browser's address bar, but that's really messy. The best option would be to trash the iframe and set up your domain and webserver to properly serve the WordPress installation. In any scenario, this isn't really a question *about* WordPress so much as it's about the `iframe` element.

Comment: Everthing @bosco said. Your issue has nothing to do with WordPress. In whichever way you build the website, if you use iframe you will always see the URL of the page that contains the iframe. You need to setup some DNS probably, but that's not something in topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the whole thing in a wrong way. First of all you should not redirect the domain to ftp server url.

You should point your domain using `A record` or `Nameservers`. Whatever option you have/works for you.

And then change `siteurl` and `home` url in your database with the new domain name. [More Details about this process](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database)

And then use a plugin like [Velvet blues update urls](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to replace old url's with new domain's url.

After doing these, your site should work fine.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I already thought I was doing something wrong. I will try this out immediatley

Comment: a little update: I've pointed nameserver 1 and 2 from my ftp server to my domain, changed the siteurl and home in wp_option in my database, updated my URLS with velvet blues update urls, but now my site still doesn't load. Any thoughts? name of the site www.jongbeleggen.com

Comment: Nameserver update may take a few hours (upto 24 hours) to propagate. Let's try after a few hours.